# What packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script?

Tags: koma-script, incompatibility

Triggered by the question [why should I not use the koma script classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73141/why-should-i-not-use-the-koma-script-classes/73206#73206) results practically necessarily a consequence question: *What packages are incompatible with `KOMA-Script`?*

`KOMA-Script` offers `scrhack` (see documentation in [KOMA-Script manual, chapter 16](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)) to fix certain well-known problems with the packages:

- `hyperref` (The `hyperref` hack in `scrhack` is only for very, very old versions of `hyperref` and does nothing for the current `hyperref` release),
- `float`,
- `floatrow`,
- `setspace` (in older versions corrections took place, in the current version no corrections are needed),
- `listings` and
- `nomencl`: The current version (year 2017) of `scrhack` provides a hack for `nomencl` that not only increases `nomencl`'s compatibility with KOMA-Script classes but also provides several new features (all from package `tocbasic`) for `nomencl`, e.g., automatic running heads or numbered heading. AFAIK this can be used not only in combination with KOMA-Script classes but also in combination with standard classes.

In the question [incompatibilities between babelfrench and koma script classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/incompatibilities-between-babelfrench-and-koma-script-classes?rq=1) special problems of `\usepackage[french][babel]` are reported.

Which packages do you know having problems with `KOMA-Script`?

Comment: `geometry` resets the from `typepage` calculated margins if you don't use the option `pass` (for `showframe`).

Comment: In the meantime, `setspace` is also supprted by `scrhack`

Comment: I'm confused on hyperref (even after checking `scrhack` docs). Is KOMAScript *broken with no workaround* with hyperref (as I thought from the question), or has the problem been fixed for good?

Comment: @Blaisorblade for current version of `hyperref` are no corections neccessary. The maintainer of `hyperref` is very active ...

Comment: Is it still true that the `setspace` package is not, or not fully, compatible with the Koma-Script document classes? The user guide mentions the `setspace` package several times -- and not in a cautionary sense.

Comment: @Mico Please see the changed question ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Markus Kohm, the author of `KOMA-Script` *(see his initials)*, utters about this frequently, but unluckily for TeX.SE usually in German.

Also I would prefer to say, some packages are not fully compatible instead of they are incompatible, because in most cases they work partially and often there’s a workaround.

- Every package, that makes a redefinition of titling and heading, is potentially not fully compatible. A well-known example is `titlesec`, where here on TeX.SE we have already a related question: [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec).
- Also packages with a heavy redefinition of footnote related stuff are potentially not fully compatible. I myself noticed, that `footnotebackref` only works with an active `symbol` (the footnote number is not turned into an active link, confer package manual).
  By the way: This works fine:

  ```
  \usepackage[symbol=${}^{\scriptscriptstyle\uparrow}$]{footnotebackref}% needs "hyperref"
  ```
- The `caption` package is according to its package documentation not fully compatible. But actually this was quite more serious in older versions both of `caption` and `KOMA-Script` (see also comment below of `caption` author Axel Sommerfeldt).
- Package `minitoc` changes `\@sect` and so breaks quite a number of KOMA-adaptions to section.
- Packages `tocloft`, `titletoc` and `tocbibind` also are not fully compatible with KOMA-script.

---

As old `scrpage2` or new `scrlayer-scrpage` is part of `KOMA-Script` *(but is a package and can be used with other classes!)*:

- Package `xwatermark` relies on `fancyhdr`, so with `scrpage2`/`scrlayer-scrpage` you will get error messages.

---

Comment: Regarding my `caption` package: The optional argument of `\setcapwidth` (offered by KOMA-Script) is the only thing I'm aware of which is not supported when loading the `caption` package. Especially everything (commands & options) the `caption` package offers IS compatible with the KOMA-Script document classes, and I'm trying hard to keep the `caption` package as compatible with KOMA-Script as possible. So in fact the `caption` package supports the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Yes, you wrote about that in the manual, and because of that I referred to it.

Comment: I for my part would say “to be expected” instead of “not fully compatible”. When I load a package like `titlesec` and use it to redefine `\chapter`, say, I cannot expect that KOMA's definition still holds... the same is true for footnotes.

Comment: @cgnieder: What? :-) It’s a different point of view, I guess, but feel free to rephrase my writing. (My English is not the best on earth.)

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Your point of view is a valid one! I just wanted to say that (and why) I see it differently.

Comment: `tocloft`, `titletoc` and `tocbibind` also are not fully compatible with KOMA-script, can you add it to the list?

Comment: [Current KOMA-Script prerelease](http://www.komascript.de/current) has a workaround for the `\@sect` issue (that seems to was an issue with `scrartcl` only). Nevertheless, there's a warning about combining `minisec` with KOMA-Script.