# scrbook and draftwatermark

Tags: backgrounds, scrbook, draftwatermark

`draftwatermark` works with  `scrbook` only in `draft` mode, however in this mode figures are not inserted. If I use the `final` mode, figures are inserted but the watermark does not show up.

```
 \documentclass[draft]{scrbook}
 \usepackage{draftwatermark}
 \begin{document}
 Hello Boulder
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can try to use some other similar packages. Harish named already one, but you will get errors, if you use `scrpage2`. I had no problems with Ahmed Musa’s earlier creation `draftmark` (`xwatermark`’s predecessor), but I put `draft `as *package* option, not in documentclass.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[color=blue!50]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understand that you want to put a watermark and that water mark is an image. But when do you want the watermark - in draft or the final version - is not clear. However, the package `xwatermark` from **Ahmed Musa** (Who is active in this forum) is better in handling such cases.

The abstract of the `xwatermark` documentation:

> The xwatermark package puts user-supplied watermarks (graphics and/or
>   arbitrary texts) on se- lect pages of documents using user-friendly
>   key-value interfaces. It has more functionality and dy- namism than,
>   for example, the packages draftcopy, draftwatermark, watermark,
>   draftmark, wallpaper. More than one (graphics and/or text) watermark
>   can be placed jointly or independ- ently on the same document page or
>   on select pages. Watermarks can be placed in the page background or
>   foreground, and watermarks can conveniently be placed on select pages
>   as rectan- gular or square tiles, depending on the user’s choice. Some
>   utility macros, namely, \xwmminipage, \xwmcolorbox, \makecolobox and
>   \fancypagenos are also provided by the package for handy use in
>   creating watermarks and for other uses. Watermarks (especially
>   wallpapers) take their toll on computer resources, especially speed
>   and save stack size. The packages in the xwatermark bundle (and
>   beyond) have been optimized as much as currently possible. In many
>   instances more than one run of the document will be needed to get the
>   watermarks on the desired pages, especially if the user calls
>   \lastdocpage to get the last page of the document.

However, the `xwatermark` has some incompatibilities with `scrpage2` as noted by **speravir** in his answer to this [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73248/what-packages-are-incompatible-with-koma-script/73288#73288)

For just text as the watermark, one can use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% \usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[draft=true,allpages=true,fontfamily=cmr,angle=90,scale=0.2,mark={\fboxsep=35pt\fboxrule=0pt\relax\fbox{-- DRAFT -- }},
color=red!75!green!50,xcoord=-80,ycoord=-20]{draftmark}
\begin{document}
Hello Boulder
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \caption{My figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the watermark is not an image it is a simple text, such as DRAFT

Comment: Ok,thanks, I guess this works, though I am worried that so many packages had to be installed by Miktex.

Comment: Note, that there’s a potential issues between `xwatermark` and `scrpage2`, cf. my answer (at the end): [What packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73248/what-packages-are-incompatible-with-koma-script/73288#73288).

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks. Good to note. I will add a note in the answer regarding this issue. Any how, victor won't be using it (looking at his requirements).

Comment: @victor: In this site, *thanks* is better conveyed by upvoting all useful answers and accepting the answer (by clicking the green check mark below the vote count) that helped you the most. This is our tradition here.

Comment: Hum, whee is that vote count?

Comment: @victor: What do you mean? (English is not my natural language.) Do you refer to Kurt’s comment under your question? Well, you should go through all of your questions and pick the answer, that helped you the most. You should see on the left of every answer below the pen quills (up- and downvote arrows) a gray hook, which turns into green, when you click on it. That’s exactly the process of accepting an answer.

Comment: @victor: See also the respective section in the [faq#reputation].