# Upper case chapter titles Tocstyle?

Tags: koma-script, tocloft, tocstyle

I would like to make table of contents in Tocstyle (standard package). Here is my code.

```
        \documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}

  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand \thesubsection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\singlespacing\rmfamily\fontsize{16pt}{19pt}\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\filcenter}{10pt}{\centering\uppercase}
{\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\filcenter}   



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

and I cannot use the following code with Tocstyle.

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\uppercase}
```

I would like to make a title of contents with all capital letters like "TEST".[image]

Comment: See BTW [What packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73288).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an `uppercase` style, similar to the definitions used by standard, but including `\MakeUppercase` (`\uppercase` in case `hyperref` is loaded):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocstyle}

\makeatletter
\newtocstyle{uppercase}{%
  \settocfeature{dothook}{\normalfont}%
  \settocfeature[0]{entryhook}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
  \settocfeature[1]{entryhook}{\MakeUppercase}%
  \settocfeature[2]{entryhook}{\MakeUppercase}%
  \settocfeature[-1]{entryvskip}{2.25em plus 1pt}%
  \settocfeature[-1]{leaders}{\hfill}%
  \settocfeature[0]{entryvskip}{1em plus 1pt}%
  \settocfeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}%
  \iftochaschapter\else
    \settocfeature[1]{entryvskip}{1em plus 1pt}%
    \settocfeature[1]{leaders}{\hfill}%
    \settocfeature[1]{entryhook}{%
      \begingroup
        \edef\@tempa{toc}%
        \ifx\tocstyleAliasTOC\@tempa\aftergroup\bfseries\fi
      \endgroup
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\usetocstyle{uppercase}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand \thesubsection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\singlespacing\rmfamily\fontsize{16pt}{19pt}\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\filcenter}{10pt}{\centering\uppercase}
{\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\filcenter}   

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way,using `titlesec` with KOMA classes might not be the best option; see [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954).

I know that perhaps you are dealing with a Faculty requirement for your thesis, but having titles and ToC entries in upper case is not the best typographical choice; at this respect, the KOMA documentation says (referring to headers, but the same can be applied to other elements):

> Unfortunately LaTeX's command for upper case letter typesetting,
>   `\MakeUppercase` results in an very inadequate typesetting, because it
>   neither uses letter spacing nor does it space balancing. One reason
>   for this behaviour might be, that a glyph analyzing would be needed,
>   to incorporate the letter shapes and their combination while space
>   balancing. Because of this KOMA-Script author suggests to abstain from
>   upper case letter typesetting for running heads.

Comment: Thanks. This is the right answer for my question but I can't use it because I still also have to edit to tocs for my thesis requirement. :(

Comment: ,I add my new question here . http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161000/upper-case-in-chapter-title-follow-up