# What packages alternatives for KOMA?

Tags: luatex, koma-script

I wanted to learn LaTeX in order to write a thesis, and also use some suggested packages to enhance it, such as:
*polyglossia, microtype, hyperref, luatextra, kpfonts, xcolor, xindy, booktabs, supertabular, longtable, flafter, fancyhdr, geometry, layaureo, indenfirst, chngpage, setspace, footmisc, bigfoot, mathtools, caption, amssymb, pgfplots, graphicx.*

[What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)

But now I'm considering to use KOMA and/or LuaTeX.

What of the aforementioned packages are not needed with KOMA or LuaTeX because they are already included, replaced by something better o just incompatible?
If they are replaced please tell the name of the new options.

There is an old similar question
[What packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73248/what-packages-are-incompatible-with-koma-script)
but it only speaks about incompatibility with KOMA and only about 5 packages. It doesn't say anything about the other packages nor unneeded ones nor LuaTeX.

Comment: You need to read KOMA documentation. It can be compiled with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, Lua... (as other document classes).

Comment: I suspect your question is "too broad" to be answered in this form but your package list contains some strange items, opmac is not for latex at all, luatextra  shouldn't be used with current luatex setup, morefloats not needed with current latex, luaotfload not usually loaded directly (but used by fontspec)

Comment: `fancyhdr` can be replaced by the KOMA package `scrlayer-scrpage`. If you still need `geometry` and `caption` with a KOMA class depends on what are really doing. `pgfplots` loads `xcolor` automatically.

Comment: Removed opmac, morefloats and luaotfload.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove `luatextra` as well? If you are going to load `fontspec`, you probably don't want to load `kpfonts`. Or check whether there is a maths-only option. If you use LuaTeX, better to stick to unicode fonts for text. What is `layeureo`? What is `flalter`?

Comment: I would suggest to start out with no packages at all, and only add packages if and when a specific need for each arises.

Comment: `microtype` is not fully compatible with LuaTeX although it is now mostly compatible. Check if the features you want are supported.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Indeed. Except maybe `microtype` and `indentfirst`. Those are never exactly *needed*.

Comment: @cfr I would like to use kpfonts or mathpazo or some nice fonts.

Comment: @skan - that is fine, of course. I was only recommending not to use a laundry-list approach to package imports without identifying the specific need for each.

Comment: So why do you want LuaTeX or `fontspec` especially? I assume `fontspec` since you listed `luaotfload` earlier apparently.

Comment: I'm just open to any suggestion.  I want to learn something but not to go back and learning something different.  I just need to use kerning and I would like to use new packages and tools such as polyglossia, xindy....

Comment: Please only use packages you actually need in your project, not a huge list of packages others use - and never use packages you don't know what they are for. There are package combinations, that can cause problems and every unnecessary package you have increases this risk and makes it more difficult to pinpoint a problem.

Comment: I have to echo the sentiment that you should focus at first creating a simple document at first. Your `documentclass` choice is a fine choice. But now that you've picked it, try to make a `.tex` file that has some section headings, a simple table, an enumerated list, some footnotes (which can all be done without loading a single package), and some math (if you're going to need it). Learn how to create simple commands and environments with `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment`. *Then* worry about whether you need to load other packages.

Comment: Yes but if I decide to start with KOMA (or memoir) that initial scheme would be different.

Comment: I've read that kpfonts are incompatible with fontspec's Luatex.  What can I do?

Comment: Do I still need geometry to define margins?